# NoSuchMethodError when calling method

Tags: kotlin

This is the code I'm running:

### higherlevel.kt

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var app = App()
    app.fibonacci(8, object : Process {
        override fun execute(value: Int) {
            println(value)
        }
    })
}

interface Process {
    fun execute(value: Int)
}

class App {
    fun fibonacci(limit: Int, action: Process) {
        var prev = 0
        var prevprev = 0
        var current = 1

        for (i: Int in 1..limit) {
            action.execute(current)

            var temp = current
            prevprev = prev
            prev = temp
            current = prev + prevprev
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: App.fibonacci(ILProcess;)V
    at HigherlevelKt.main(higherlevel.kt:3)
```

When I **recompile the code**, it runs just fine.

[image]

When I **rebuild the project** & run the program again, it yields that same error.

[image]

What is really happening ?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.1 EAP, & the Kotlin compiler version **1.1.2-2**

Comment: The code works for me. Are you sure, your IDE plugin is up to date? IDEA 2017.1.1 EAP is pretty outdated, please update to the stable version.

Comment: I'll update to version 2017.1.3 (the latest one) & see if this behavior still remains.